# Json to Dataframe python

Tags: python, json, dataframe

Hi I am working on huge JSON file with different values length/key. The file is like this:

````
```
 {"554": [2835, 4518, 2198, 2014, 3818, 3045, 4570, 4585, 4596, 4599, 4609, 4617, 4627, 4641, 4643, 4651, 4665, 4676, 4682, 4694, 4696, 4708], "10772": [3293, 2534, 979, 2014, 2317], "6350": [4477, 2895, 4039, 3282, 765, 2669], "9218": [3133, 2052, 979, 3355, 107, 1878, 1105, 4571, 4582, 4593, 4598, 4609, 4619, 4629, 4636, 4642, 4652, 4662, 4675, 4683, 4689, 4704, 4713]....}
```
````

Because of the different length in value, I didn't find an easy way to save it in a dataFrame.
So I did right this code that goes to each key and finds its values and save it to dict_df.loc[i] raw by raw the code goes like this:

```
with open('data.json') as json_data:
features_dataframe = json.load(json_data)
```

And I defined the dataframe columns like this:

```
dict_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id_1','id_2'])
```

And now the masterbeas function:

```
i=0
percentige=1

for key in features_dataframe.keys():
    for valueInKeyLen in range(len(features_dataframe[key])):
        dict_df.loc[i]=[key,features_dataframe[key][valueInKeyLen]]
        i=i+1
        if i == valueInKeyLen:
            i=i+1
            break
```

The code works fine but is so slow and ugly how can make it faster and shorter ?

Comment: ``pd.DataFrame(data=features_dataframe.items(), columns=['id_1','id_2']).explode(column='id_2')`` ?

Comment: wow I feel so stupid no its works fine